# PHP execute function when is previous execution done in loop

Tags: php, cron

How to execute function in loop ONLY when is previous execution done?

I use one API where I need to send email to 2000 users per each session automaticly. I use corn job for that but I need to create some kind of pagination in database becouse I currently have arround 50.000 users. I know how to create pagination and send in loop but problem is server time. Execution of script is arround 5 min what return me error 500. Provider not allow me to expand execution time.

I need in PHP to Send first 2000 emails, after execution to start new execution etc. I try with ajax and work perfect but cronjob not execute HTML.

What to do?

Here is AJAX solution:

```
(function($){
    var setup = {
        page    : 0,
        total   : 30
    }, 
    sendAjax = function(page){
        if(page > setup.total)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ajax/daily-request.php",
                type:"POST",
                data: "page="+page+"&total="+setup.total
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                console.log("AJAX Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }).done(function(num){
                num = $.trim(num);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    sendAjax(num);
                    console.log("User Group "+num+" Request Send!");

                    ////////// DEBUG //////////
                    // sendAjax(setup.page);
                    // console.log(setup.page);
                    // setup.page++;
                },1);
            });
        }   
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        sendAjax(setup.page);
    }); 
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: When triggering cron send a get var with the amount of data required to send then just add another cron job for each group but add a delay of about 1 min before each group triggers

Comment: I don't know how mutch group I will have in future. Total number is automaticly generated

Comment: U can how ever make the page loop with header at the end that increases the number the triggers its self again till end so header(self.php?group=1000

Comment: Realy? How to do that? That will be awsome solution.

Comment: have left answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your PHP

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) $_GET["page"] : 0 ;//get page or handle first 1st page

using $page you can use your pagination to handle pages 0-infinate

.... your email loop for first 1000 emails
.... check that there is more
if($page != $lastpage){
header("location: daily-request.php?page=".($page+1));
}    
//end of the file
?>
```

this will force the file to reload with a new page until it has none left
setting it to 1000 ensures that you will not be sending to many on page allowing the server time to switch the pages without timeout's.

for the sql bit all u need to do is

```
$start = $page*1000;
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $start, 1000;
```

this way you do not have to edit cron job just let it run and the file will take over after the first ini of it, then it will stop when pages run out and stop the loop;

Comment: This is awsome, I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

I read your problem very carefully .All you need to do is just use 'sleep()' function in php which will make your server sleep for given min so that you server will not give 500 error.

Comment: Are you shure that sleep() can help?

Comment: ya i am damn sure.. I have done this kinda stuff...and sleep() function worked like charm :)

Comment: Thanks! I use usleep for this proplem to delay 500ms after all updates before redirections.